# Can't find .htaccess file in mamp on Mac

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authorization

I want to be able to send an authenticated requests via http header when I'm in localhost, but I can't do that before adding this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

to my .htaccess file, but I can't find the file. I have enable to see alle hidden files, but none of them is .htaccess. Hope you guys can help - Thank you.

PS I'm using this guide which tell me what to do to make send a http header reqeust when on localhost: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication

Answer (score 0):

[A `.htaccess` file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) won't be created by Apache automatically. You have to create it yourself (or use the regular configuration files, which would be slightly more efficient is the method recommended by the Apache documentation).

Comment: the regular configuration files, which ones do you mean. thank you.

Comment: The ones in /etc/apache2

Comment: Where should i place the .htaccess file? in the root folder of mamp?

Comment: In the directory you want it to apply to